# TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src' - Python

Tags: python-3.8, opencv, python

I am loading some images using the following python code and getting the below error.

```
import os
data_dir = os.path.abspath("/dogslist")
os.path.exists(data_dir)

def resize_cv(im):
    return cv2.resize(im, (64, 64))

lstImages = []

for item in lstImages:
    resize_cv(item)
    cv2.imread(item)
    list_images.append(item)     
    images.append(images[img])
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'
```

Comment: for item in lstImages:
    resize_cv(item)
    cv2.imread(item)
    lstImages.append(item)

Answer (score 0):

Calling `os.path.exists(data_dir)` wouldn't do anything as it only returns a boolean value. You'll need to put it in a condition, like this:

```
if os.path.exists(data_dir):
    print("Exists")
else:
    print("Doesn't exist")
```

Since your line to make sure that images exist didn't work properly, most likely you were getting the error from attempting cv2 commands on a file that didn't exist; opencv wouldn't tell you when your trying to open a file that doesn't exist, it will return an empty array.

Comment: import os
data_dir = os.path.abspath("/dogslist")
if os.path.exists(data_dir):
    print("Exists")
else:
    print("Doesn't exist")

def resize_cv(im):
    return cv2.resize(im, (64, 64))

lstImages = []
list_images = []

for item in os.listdir(data_dir):
    lstImages.append(item)

for item in lstImages:
    resize_cv(item)
    cv2.imread(item)
    list_images.append(item)     
 cv2.waitKey(1000)

print("count")
print(list_images.count()) 

after alter the code like above still the same error 

TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'

Comment: @ChandraRas Did `Exists` get printed or `Doesn't exist`?